# Insert the contents of a textbox as paragraph text dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I am trying to dynamically add the text from the input box into a paragraph (at the top of the page, under the 2 headlines).

I have a JSFiddle that I am working with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shannongmac/T7LeW/11/#&togetherjs=nSDqSDGeMh)

This is my function:

```
    function addText() {
            var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
        newParagraph.textContent = textArea;
        document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(newParagraph);
        myDiv.insertBefore(newParagraph, textArea);
        }

    document.getElementById("textArea").onblur = addText;
```

However, as you can see, on the onblur, it is doing this: [object HTMLTextAreaElement]

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: this works: http://jsfiddle.net/shannongmac/T7LeW/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the textArea as the text inside the newParagraph. As it expects a string, is is converting the textArea into a string representation, which is "[object HTMLTextAreaElement]"

Instead, do this:

```
newParagraph.textContent = textArea.value;
```

Then, your code would be:

```
    function addText() {

        var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');

        newParagraph.textContent = textArea.value;
        document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(newParagraph);
        myDiv.insertBefore(newParagraph, textArea);

    }

    document.getElementById("textArea").onblur = addText;
```

As you told me you want to prepend the new paragraph, use the following:

```
     parentObject.insertBefore(newParagraph, parentObject.firstChild);
```

Hope I helped you out!

Comment: Thanks! Ok it's adding it at the bottom, not the top, but I think I can work on that!

Comment: It is adding at the bottom because you are appending the newParagraph. Prepend it so it will work as expected! :)

Comment: Oh! I got it! I needed to do: document.getElementById("id1").insertBefore(newParagraph, textArea)
 myDiv.insertBefore(newParagraph, textArea);